# JavaScript `for in` returning sorted items

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

I'm curious, I noticed, while running a `for in` on an object with numeric keys. The items seem to be consistently returning sorted. Anyone able to explain why this is?

```js
const thing = {
  "2": "any",
  "8": "thing",
  "3": "here",
  "7": "x",
  "6": "xx",
  "1": "xxx"
};

for (var item in thing) {
  console.log(item);
}
```

Comment: Because objects don't have any order. And keeping integer-named properties in ascending sequence is an easy engine optimisation.

Comment: @Bergi I do know in JS that order is never guaranteed, but are you saying JS will do internal sorting if the keys are numbers?

Comment: Engines do what they want....

Comment: Even without the `for..in`, the optimization is there `JSON.stringify(thing)` => 
`"{"1":"xxx","2":"any","3":"here","6":"xx","7":"x","8":"thing"}"` (at least in Chrome)

Comment: I believe, some engines optimize objects with only integer (or integer-like) keys – especially very small ones – by representing them arrays.

Comment: @Bergi thanks! Now I'm curious, how does sorting them provide any optimisation? Additionally, why not sort strings as well?

Comment: @VinnieJames It's just that integer properties are stored as an array while others are stored in a hash table or in order of occurrence.

Comment: I see, @Bergi Why is it that sorting the items before they are stored in the array is faster (optimized) than sorting unordered integers in the array?

Comment: They're not "sorted". It's just that the values of integer properties are stored in a *linear* array, which makes them fast to lookup by pointer.